# calling a function while in it

Tags: python, function

```
def move(list, wins_1, wins_2):
    global turn
    if turn % 2 == 0:
        sign = "| x "
    else:
        sign = "| o "
y_1 = int(input("Type the value of y: "))
x_1 = int(input("Type the value of x: "))

if list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1] == "| x " or list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1] == "| o ":
    print("The place is already filled by %s |" % list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1])
    move(list, wins_1, wins_2)
else:
    list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1] = sign

print_board(list)  #

wins_1, wins_2 = check_winner(sign, wins_1, wins_2)

turn += 1
return wins_1, wins_2
```

If the user input the [x][y] of a list and its already taken by a x or o (its a tic tac toe game) it should print("this place is already filled") and then make the user type another set of x and y to put his x/o.

That made me think, maybe I could just simply call the function and make it repeat itself. It worked fine, no error. 
But for some reason it printed my board two (or for how many times i have pressed the "x" and "y" for an already filled place) many times.

Can someone explain what happens when you call a function when you are in the function. And what exactly happened in my code?

NOTE: my code is very long this is just a little bit of it. If there is a need for more code, let me know.

Here is an example of the output: note that it prints the board 2 times after putted the x/o in an already filled place.

```
Type the name of player 1: 1
type the name of player 2: 1
____________________________________________________________
player_1: 1       X        wins: 0
player_2: 1       O        wins: 0
____________________________________________________________
Type the value of y: 1
Type the value of x: 1
 -------------
 | x |   |   |   
 -------------
 |   |   |   |   
 -------------
 |   |   |   |   
 -------------
____________________________________________________________
player_1: 1       X        wins: 0
player_2: 1       O        wins: 0
____________________________________________________________
Type the value of y: 1
Type the value of x: 1
The place is already filled by | x  |
Type the value of y: 1
Type the value of x: 2
 -------------
 | x | o |   |   
 -------------
 |   |   |   |   
 -------------
 |   |   |   |   
 -------------
 -------------
 | x | o |   |   
 -------------
 |   |   |   |   
 -------------
 |   |   |   |   
 -------------
____________________________________________________________
player_1: 1       X        wins: 0
player_2: 1       O        wins: 0
____________________________________________________________
Type the value of y:
```

The whole code:

```
wins_1 = 0
wins_2 = 0
turn = 0
board = [
        ['|   ', '|   ', '|   ', '|   '],
        ['|   ', '|   ', '|   ', '|   '],
        ['|   ', '|   ', '|   ', '|   ']
    ]
def print_board(board_list):

    for i in range(len(board_list)):
        print(" -------------\n %s" % "".join(board_list[i]))  # .join binder 2 items sammen.
    print(" -------------")

player_1 = input("Type the name of player 1: ")
player_2 = input("type the name of player 2: ")
def game_info(player_1, player_2, wins_1, wins_2):  # prints layout
    print("_" * 60)
    print("player_1: %s       X        wins: %s"
          "\nplayer_2: %s       O        wins: %s"
          % (str(player_1), str(wins_1), str(player_2), str(wins_2)))
   print("_" * 60)
# ovenstående viser output af wins og navn



def print_winner(sign, wins_1, wins_2):

    if sign == "| x ":
        print("%s got 3 in a row, %s wins!" % (player_1, player_1))
        wins_1 += 1
    else:
        print("%s got 3 in a row, %s wins!" % (player_2, player_2))
        wins_2 += 1
    return wins_1, wins_2


def check_winner(sign, wins_1, wins_2):

    # check vertical:    |
    for x in range(0,3):
        if board[0][x] == sign and board[1][x] == sign and board[2][x] == sign:
            wins_1, wins_2 = print_winner(sign, wins_1, wins_2)

    #  check horizontal: -
    for x in range(0, 3):
        if board[x][0] == sign and board[x][1] == sign and board[x][2] == sign:
            wins_1, wins_2 = print_winner(sign, wins_1, wins_2)

    #  check diagonal:   \
    if board[0][0] == sign and board[1][1] == sign and board[2][2] == sign:
        wins_1, wins_2 = print_winner(sign, wins_1, wins_2)
    elif board[0][2] == sign and board[1][1] == sign and board[2][0] == sign:
        wins_1, wins_2 = print_winner(sign, wins_1, wins_2)

    return wins_1, wins_2


def move(list, wins_1, wins_2):
    global turn
    if turn % 2 == 0:
        sign = "| x "
    else:
        sign = "| o "

    y_1 = int(input("Type the value of y: "))
    x_1 = int(input("Type the value of x: "))

    if list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1] == "| x " or list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1] == "| o ":
        print("The place is already filled by %s |" % list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1])
        move(list, wins_1, wins_2)
    else:
        list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1] = sign

    print_board(list)  #

    wins_1, wins_2 = check_winner(sign, wins_1, wins_2)

    turn += 1
    return wins_1, wins_2





while True:
    game_info(player_1, player_2, wins_1, wins_2)
    wins_1, wins_2 = move(board, wins_1, wins_2)  # move() sætter et 'tegn' og returner win1/win2

    if wins_1 or wins_2 == 1:
        break
print("*****************************************************\nGame Over.    \n IT WORKED!")
```

Comment: intendation is dubious. Is this the `move` method in the end ? or some other method? method shouldn't call itself when there's an input problem.

Comment: Hello Sebastian, could you please include the whole code? If you want you can just copy and paste and I will change it into code format for you, Then I can look at the whole code and run it properly.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sebastian3495/6c856c6d7f93f629f91496893c2b5cfb
take a look at the whole code.

Comment: You need to be careful as the user can input y:1 x:4

Comment: as I said, my code isnt finnished yet, i'll work on that later.
For now, all I focus on is to make sure that the player cant put x/o on a place thats already been filled.

Comment: I was just telling you as something you could add when complete, in case you hadn't realised

Comment: I have added an answer for you, all you need to do it copy and paste into your code. I have already implemented it into your code. Alternatively, you can just write in my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
def move(list, wins_1, wins_2):
    printed = False
    global turn
    if turn % 2 == 0:
        sign = "| x "
    else:
        sign = "| o "

    y_1 = int(input("Type the value of y: "))
    x_1 = int(input("Type the value of x: "))

    if list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1] == "| x " or list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1] == "| o ":
        print("The place is already filled by %s |" % list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1])
        move(list, wins_1, wins_2)
        printed = True
    else:
        list[y_1 - 1][x_1 - 1] = sign

    if printed == False:
        print_board(list)  

    wins_1, wins_2 = check_winner(sign, wins_1, wins_2)

    turn += 1
    return wins_1, wins_2
```

I have added a variable called `printed` so it only prints once

This then allows your program only to print if it hasn't printed already

Hope this has helped :)

Comment: edit: nvm, i overlooked something u changed in my code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's ok! Glad I could help. If you ever get the chance to +1 my answer, it would also really help me!

Comment: I would but unfortunately I am not able to do so. Because I am a new user.

Comment: I was only saying for when you have enough reputation to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

You're entering an infinite loop. You're running through `move` the first time. Then you start `move` a second time. Assuming the second `move` finishes, then your program will pick up where it left off in the first `move` which called the second. As long as that `if list` is true, you'll instantiate another instance of `move`.

What you want to achieve is `recursion` a simple example would be.

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

You can track how the function works by adding two print() function to the previous function definition:

```
def factorial(n):
    print("factorial has been called with n = " + str(n))
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        res = n * factorial(n-1)
        print("intermediate result for ", n, " * factorial(" ,n-1, "): ",res)
        return res  

print(factorial(5))
```

Output:

```
factorial has been called with n = 5
factorial has been called with n = 4
factorial has been called with n = 3
factorial has been called with n = 2
factorial has been called with n = 1
intermediate result for  2  * factorial( 1 ):  2
intermediate result for  3  * factorial( 2 ):  6
intermediate result for  4  * factorial( 3 ):  24
intermediate result for  5  * factorial( 4 ):  120
120
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didnt quite get that, how am I supposed to implement that in my code?

Comment: First my 1. call of the "move" function started, then when I called the "move" function again. 
Did the first "move" function then finnish, and then the second function began. Or did my second function first run as I called it and when that finnished, my 1. "move" function would run?
It's a little bit cunfusing..

Comment: EDIT: can u think of an alternative to solve this problem?
Remember that it should keep asking for a new input, if the place already is taken, that is my goal.

Comment: @sebastian your first move will NEVER finish until your second finishes. Similarly, if your second move spams a 3rd move then neither 1 nor 2 will finish until 3 finishes. You're creating a potentially infinite stack of moves as long as the `if` condition is true.

Comment: The point is that as long as you just call `move` you have no possible escape condition. Your method `move` should have 2 return conditions just like the example above. `1 to call itself so return move(list, wins_1, wins_2)` and the other escape condition is so that it can break out of the infinite list, so in your case when all 9 places are taken, we don't care who won just that the game is over.

Comment: @sebastian if this is for school `printed` is a bad way to do it btw, prof will probably deduct marks. It's bad practice. Good luck :)